# How is No for an answer to a question that invites workarounds?

Tags: discussion, answers, voting

The upvote arrow tooltip reads

> This answer is useful

"How to answer" reads

> Make sure your answer provides [what is asked] – or a viable alternative. .. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful ...

**Then how good is**

> No [some fluff that is not helping either]

**as an answer to questions that invite workarounds?**  People might not know what others can come up with. I'm sure a lot of people sometimes get surprised by how someone else does the same thing in an unexpected way.

Reasons why I don't like them:

- Saying no simply implies

  > I don't know how to do that.

  which is clearly not a helpful response to a question. If a question is left unanswered, it means that those who saw it didn't know what to do.
- It might discourage some other answerers from finding workarounds.
- As one's reputation increases, the *weight* of their *No* also increases.

Samples (and a customary *I'm not calling out*):

- [Shortcuts-app automation to prevent iPhone screen from going to sleep](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373189/shortcuts-app-automation-to-prevent-iphone-screen-from-going-to-sleep/373191#373191)
- [Shortcut to toggle EU Volume Limit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372921/shortcut-to-toggle-eu-volume-limit/373146#373146)
- [After upgrading to Catalina, is there a way to remote control the Apple Music app on my desktop?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372650/after-upgrading-to-catalina-is-there-a-way-to-remote-control-the-apple-music-ap/373088#373088)

Midway:

- [Disable the do not disturb banner on iOS 13 notification centre](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372846/disable-the-do-not-disturb-banner-on-ios-13-notification-centre/373183#373183)
- [iPhone 11 - Leave lock screen after FaceId](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373083/iphone-11-leave-lock-screen-after-faceid/373084#373084)
- [Are frayed cables of Apple lightning cord or Macbook Power Adapter covered by warranty?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372803/are-frayed-cables-of-apple-lightning-cord-or-macbook-power-adapter-covered-by-wa/372804#372804)

Nice ones:

- [How to permanently delete pictures from all devices in Apple ecosystem?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372926/how-to-permanently-delete-pictures-from-all-devices-in-apple-ecosystem/372956#372956)
- [How to install apps on iPad 4 which require IOS version 11 or higher?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372626/how-to-install-apps-on-ipad-4-which-require-ios-version-11-or-higher/372632#372632)

A fun and a bit related question on Math meta:

[Is it okay to give an answer with only “Yes” or “No” with no further details supporting the conclusion?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30788/is-it-okay-to-give-an-answer-with-only-yes-or-no-with-no-further-details-sup)

Comment: Intentional voting tag there. :)

Comment: Not sure what your question is or what you expect as answers? Even if you think some people vote „wrong“: how do you intend to change that?

Comment: Should it be downvoted or removed as NAA or VLQ ? I used bold tho

Comment: I could reduce the vote by one. That's the best I could do anyway.

Comment: The three samples are just plainly bad or incomplete answers (at least lacking a source for the statement made) and should be handled as such.

Comment: Sometimes such answers are also an indication for a question which can/should be improved

Comment: I forgot to add the best one so far :p [Is there an equivalent to the Windows 7 Problem Steps Recorder on macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/68884/313842) And this justifies what you just said: " for a question which can/should be improved"

Comment: Downvote and move on

Comment: Lol okay.. Nice that I am not on the brink of 3k now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes, the correct answer is a simple 'no' **with** an explanation why it is what it is.  Not all answer have to be, or need to be, complicated.  In fact, providing someone a complicated workaround could actually make the situation worse.

Your assumption that a simple answer means "I don't know how to do that" is a bit faulty.

I'm not saying it's entirely incorrect because sometimes that is the case.  It's been my experience (a few years on this site and sites similar) that if a workaround is possible, someone will add it as either a comment ("hey, what about doing....?") or a more detailed answer ("I couldn't do it that way but I could do it this way....").

I believe flagging an answer that only provides a yes or no without anything to back it up is completely acceptable.  I would also add, telling the writer why you flagged their answer helps them learn how to craft **better** answers.  After all, our goal is to help people and that includes answer-writers.

Comment: thanks for adding bold on "with".. Still had to read it twice ^^'